# fmemopen error on mac os x

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, opticalflow

I'd like to compile some code using makefile.
Those codes are implemented from "Computing Inverse Optical Flow, Javier et al., 2013"
When I compiled codes, I got the error below, so I tried add "fmemopen" files from "https://github.com/materialsvirtuallab/pyhull/tree/master/src/fmemopen" as it said. 
But I still have the same error, I think "_read_image_f in iio.o" is the problem here. I don't know how to figure out this problem. Please help me out.

```
jeongHyunseonui-MacBook-Pro:inverse_flow hyunseon$ make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -pedantic -O4 -o backward_flow backward_flow.cpp iio.o -lpng -ljpeg -ltiff
clang: warning: -O4 is equivalent to -O3
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_fmemopen", referenced from:
  _read_image_f in iio.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [backward_flow] Error 1
```

Comment: You aren't linking-in the object files or library containing the `fmemopen()` function.  You will have to modify the `Makefile`.

Comment: [fmemopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) is a Linux (or rather POSIX) thing - it doesn't exist on Mac OS X (or BSD in general). Either set up a Linux VM on your OS X box, or use a Linux box, or be prepared to do some porting work.

Comment: @Droppy: aha - missed that - thanks.

Comment: @PaulR `fmemopen` seems to be available on macOS since 10.13.`cat /usr/include/stdio.h | grep fmemopen` gives me `FILE *fmemopen( [...] ) __API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));`.

Comment: @dnlggr: thanks - good to know.